# How do I analyse the time complexity of the following nested loop and what would be value of count in terms of n?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, runtime

I want the time complexity of this in big-oh $O$ aswell as value of count in terms of $n$

```java
count = 0;
for (i = 1; i < n; i=i*2) {
    for (j = 1; j < i; j = j + 1) {
        count = count + 1;
    } 
}
```

Since, I can't LaTeX here, I am attaching my solution in my screenshot:

[image: My Solution]

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your analysis is correct and your conclusion is correct; the running time is asymptotically O(n). Not much else to say.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: After plotting first 100 000 numbers plot is very similar to 0(nlog) plot[image: function plot], after some approximations, so that's ~O(nlogn)[image: complexity]

Comment: are you sure about this? I dont think inner loop is going O(n)

Comment: Obviously we can approximate numbers of iterations for n

Comment: It's similar to an O(log n) plot because your y axis is logarithmic!